# How to get for loop to print the total of something instead of each individual component?

Tags: java, loops

```
if(Payment.pay.isEmpty()) 
                        Payment.fillList();{
                    }
                        double total = 0.0;
                        for(Payment payment : Payment.pay){
                            if(payment.getCustomerNumber() == customer.getCustomerNumber()){
                                    total += payment.getAmount();      
                            }   
                        } 
                        //System.out.println(total); 
                    if(Employee.emp.isEmpty()) {
                        Employee.fillList();
                    }
                    double revenue = 0;
                    for(Employee employee : Employee.emp) {
                        if(employee.getEmployeeNumber() == customer.getSalesRepEmployeeNum()) {
                            //total += total;
                            System.out.println("Employee: " + employee.getEmployeeNumber() + " Revenue: " + total);
                        }
                    }
```

At the moment my code collects the total payments made by one customer. And then I want to output the total revenue made by one employee who can serve multiple customers. However, it's only showing the revenue for one customer each instead of adding together all the sales from that one employee its displaying them all separately so it's printing the employee multiple times with different revenues instead of adding them together for a grand total. How do I change this?

Comment: int sum = 0; for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {sum += foo[i].value;}

Comment: Thanks. I am confused as to where to put it in my code and what values to substitute however

Answer (score 0):

As NomadMaker mentions, you can add a loop to calculate the value *if it were in an array*. 
But from what I understand, there is no list or array for each employee which contains his sales. Once you have that, you can iterate through it, adding to sum total.
I'm having trouble understanding the structure of your data, but in general, I would add a field in the Employee class holding `int revenue` and just add to it every time a payment is made.